# Cannot get smo object for ManagedComputer

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have been using the MSDN article [Enable or Disable a Server Network Protocol (SQL Server PowerShell)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206997.aspx) and am running into issues on the line:

```
$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='<computer_name>']/ ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Np']"
```

The error message I get is:

```
Exception calling "GetSmoObject" with "1" argument(s): "Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for ManagedComputer '<computer_name>'."
At line:1 char:24
+ $Np = $wmi.GetSmoObject <<<< ($uri)
    + CategoryInfo           : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId  : DotNetMethodException
```

I am replacing `<computer_name>` with the name of my computer.  I have also tried omitting `<computer_name>` from my command (I am trying to configure the machine from which I am running the script), and the I get the same error, including it showing the correct `<computer_name>` in the error.  I have also tried omitting everything from the first `/` on, with no luck.

I have tried using `cmd`, `powershell`, and `sqlps`.  I am logged in as Administrator, and all of my windows say Administrator at the top, so I take that to mean that I am running the commands as administrator.

I am running on Windows Server 2012, with MS Sql Server 2012 installed.

My long term goal is to create a utility to setup SQL Server on a new machine without the need for user interaction.

How can I resolve my issue with the line of code from the MSDN article?

Comment: As written the code will only work on a default instance. Are you by chance using a named instance?

Comment: @ChadMiller I believe I am using the default instance.  I don't specify an instance name when I log-in through SSMS, and when I do `SELECT @@SERVICE` the result is `MSSQLSERVER`.

Comment: I included this line at the beginning of the powershell script: `Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNamechecking` and went back to explicitly putting in the `<computer_name>`, and now it works.  I think I was getting errors because of not doing the import module, but by the time I imported it, I started leaving the computer name blank, and started getting XPath errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included this line at the beginning of the powershell script:

```
Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNamechecking
```

and went back to explicitly putting in the `<computer_name>`, and now it works.

I think I was getting errors because of not doing the import module, but by the time I imported it, I started leaving the computer name blank, and started getting XPath errors.

Comment: My issue was similar... I had the computer name in a variable and therefore thought I didn't need quotes around it.  Turns out, it needs quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you failed like me for SQLExpress (version 12 = 2014):

look at this registry location:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp

the manager shows the value, but I cannot change the values in Win10 - UI issue.
C:\Windows\System32\SQLServerManager12.msc

Answer (score 1):

Enable TCP and Named Pipes on a Named SQL Server instance
Tested against Server 2022 Express

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement")

$smo = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.'  
$wmi = new-object ($smo + 'Wmi.ManagedComputer').
$SQLInstance = $wmi.ServerInstances.Name

#note the dynamic retrieval of the instance name; obviously, this would not work if you had more than one named instance installed on the machine
$uri = "$($wmi.urn.value)/ServerInstance[@Name=`'$SQLInstance`']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']"
$Tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)
$Tcp.IsEnabled = $true
$Tcp.Alter()
$uri = "$($wmi.urn.value)/ ServerInstance[@Name=`'$SQLInstance`']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Np']"
$Np = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)
$Np.IsEnabled = $true
$Np.Alter()

Restart-Service "MSSQL`$$($SQLInstance)"
```